# How can I describe that Word template features are only in US Letter format?

Tags: word-usage

I have a data sheet for:

> A4 (210mm x 297mm) & US Letter (8.5" x 11")

For the US Letter I wish to describe that the templates we provide in that format are only in Word, while for A4, we provide templates in Word and Writer. How can I point it out?

> A4 (210mm x 297mm) & US Letter (8.5" x 11"*) * *explicit MS Word format*

I'm not sure "explicit" is the right word.

Comment: @WeatherVane, there's a [meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/did-i-edit-too-much/10464) for everyone to voice their opinions on this.

Comment: What do you mean by "Writer"?

Comment: Your title and body say two different things. Title: "The templates in Word are only in US Letter format" Body: "The formats for US letter are only in Word."

Comment: What's wrong with the word "only"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think *explicit* works terribly well.  How about

***[available](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/available)***

> Capable of being obtained or used (American Heritage)

Here's an example of how this can be used in promotional materials:

> This software comes in Lite and Full versions.  The Full version is only available for (such and so operating system).